# Count word frequency using map

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, operator-overloading

This is my first time implementing map in C++. So given a character array with text, I want to count the frequency of each word occurring in the text. I decided to implement map to store the words and compare following words and increment a counter. 
Following is the code I have written so far.

```
  const char *kInputText = "\
  So given a character array with text, I want to count the frequency of
  each word occurring in the text.\n\
  I decided to implement map to store the\n\
  words and compare following words and increment a counter.\n";      

  typedef struct WordCounts
  {
       int wordcount;
  }WordCounts;

  typedef map<string, int> StoreMap;

  //countWord function is to count the total number of words in the text.
  void countWord( const char * text, WordCounts & outWordCounts )
  {
       outWordCounts.wordcount = 0;
       size_t i;
       if(isalpha(text[0]))
            outWordCounts.wordcount++;
       for(i=0;i<strlen(text);i++)
       {
            if((isalpha(text[i])) && (!isalpha(text[i-1])))
                 outWordCounts.wordcount++;
       }
       cout<<outWordCounts.wordcount;
  }

  //count_for_map() is to count the word frequency using map.
  void count_for_map(const char *text, StoreMap & words)
  {
       string st;
       while(text >> st)
            words[st]++;
  }

  int main()
  {
       WordCounts wordCounts;
       StoreMap w;
       countWord( kInputText, wordCounts );
       count_for_map(kInputText, w);
       for(StoreMap::iterator p = w.begin();p != w.end();++p)
       {
             std::cout<<p->first<<"occurred" <<p->second<<"times. \n";
       }
       return 0;
  }



  Error: No match for 'operator >>' in 'text >> st'
  I understand this is an operator overloading error, so I went ahead and
  wrote the following lines of code.
  //In the count_for_map()
       /*istream & operator >> (istream & input,const char *text)
       {
             int i;
             for(i=0;i<strlen(text);i++)
                 input >> text[i];
             return input;
       }*/
  Am I implementing map in the wrong way?
```

Comment: You should probably also describe your error in the main text above the code, since readers currently have to sift through your code to figure out what the problem is that you are having.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no overload for `>>` with a `const char*` left hand side.

`text` is a `const char*`, not an `istream`, so your overload doesn't apply (and the overload 1: is wrong, and 2: already exists in the standard library).

You want to use the more suitable `std::istringstream`, like this:

```
std::istringstream textstream(text);
while(textstream >> st)
    words[st]++;
```

Comment: +1, minor nitpick though: there's "text," and "text." which will get counted as separate words in the string, so you'll want to remove the punctuation marks first.

Comment: This works perfectly! But when I tried to move the for loop containing the iterator from the main() to count_for_map(), I get an error saying 'w' is not initialized. But I have initialized w in main().

Comment: @user2948246 Giving things the same name doesn't make them the same thing. If you have declared one variable "w" in `main`and one "w" in another function, those are completely different and independent variables.

Comment: My bad wrong question. So like I said I shifted the for loop containing the iterator into `count_for_map()`. But I noticed that when i ran it, the text in the `text_array` prints out junk values in between and the count for the word frequency is messed up, as opposed to when the for loop with the iterator is `main()` and the output is perfect. 
The reason I want to shift the for loop is because I want to print the words with certain frequency. 
    `for(StoreMap::iterator p = w.begin();p != w.end();++p)
    {
        std::cout<<p->first<<" occurred " <<p->second<<" times. \n";
    }`

Answer (score 0):

If you use modern C++ language, then life will get by far easier.

First. Usage of a `std::map` is the correct approach.

This is a more or less standard approach for counting something in a container.

We can use an associative container like a `std::map` or a `std::unordered_map`. And here we associate a "key", in this case the "word" to count, with a value, in this case the count of the specific word.

And luckily the maps have a very nice index operator[]. This will look for the given key and if found, return a reference to the value. If not found, the it will create a new entry with the key and return a reference to the new entry. So, in bot cases, we will get a reference to the value used for counting. And then we can simply write:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, unsigned int> counter{};
counter[word]++;
```

But how to get words from a string. A string is like a container containing elements. And in C++ many containers have iterators. And especially for strings there is a dedicated iterator that allows to iterate over patterns in a `std::string`. It is called `std::sregex_token_iterator` and described [here.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_token_iterator). The pattern is given as a `std::regex` which will give you a great flexibility.

And, because we have such a wonderful and dedicated iterator, we should use it!

Eveything glued together will give a very compact solution, with a minimal number of code lines.

Please see:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <map>
#include <iomanip>

const std::regex re{ "\\w+" };
const std::string text{ R"(So given a character array with text, I want to count the frequency of 
each word occurring in the text. 
I decided to implement map to store the
words and compare following words and increment a counter.")" };


int main() {
    std::map<std::string, unsigned int> counter{};

    for (auto word{ std::sregex_token_iterator(text.begin(),text.end(),re) }; word != std::sregex_token_iterator(); ++word)
        counter[*word]++;

    for (const auto& [word, count] : counter) 
        std::cout << std::setw(20) << word << "\toccurred\t" << count << " times\n";
}
```